# Missing \endgroup inserted error in equation in latex?

Tags: latex

`\[ P(F=f|S=s)=\frac{$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}}{n}  \]`

I don't seem to get the error! I want to write a conditional probability function and it won't let me :(

Answer (score 3):

The error arises, since you start the math mode (...{`$`\sum...}), but don't close it within the curly bracket.

Use $..$ to start and end a math formula inline:

```
$P(F=f|S=s) = \frac{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}}{n}$
```

Use \[ .. \] to start and end a math formula in e new line:

```
\[P(F=f|S=s) = \frac{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}}{n}\]
```

---

Small Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
Use \$ .. \$ to start and end a math formula inline:

$P(F=f|S=s) = \frac{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}}{n}$ \\

Use  \textbackslash[ .. \textbackslash] to start and end a math formula in e new line:

\[P(F=f|S=s) = \frac{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}}{n}\]
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: LaTeX-Output]

Further Information:

[Wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics)